# Visual studio crash on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash

I have a problem with running Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I start visual studio and wait to load Start page. It is ok. But when I move with mouse, visual studio crash without any error message. I tried run visual studio in /safemode, no change, the same problem. Then i try run it with /log parameter to look for errors in %appdata%/....., but the file doesn't constaints any error item. Reinstall didn't work. Anyone can help me? Thanks. (Sorry for my EN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Finally!!! Visual Studio have turned on HW acceleration on graphics card. Turn off the HW acceleration in visual studio solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It is an normal problem i have seen in 2013 version, i would recommend you to use Visual studio 2015 professional instead, it's  much more useful with some extra features and more user friendly.Try downloading it.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you for now